# Pressing toggle button in toggle group calls more than one button

Tags: c#, android, ios, mobile, unity-game-engine

In my unity game I have two toggle buttons that are both in a toggle group together. They are buttons that are labeled "On" and "Off" for turning the game music on and off.

The way I have it set up right now makes it behave very strange. If the music is on and I click the "Off" toggle, the music turns off. Then if I hit "On" again, I get a null object reference error and the check mark doesn't show up in the "On" toggle button until I hit "On" a second time and then the sound comes back on. The really weird part is that when it turns back on, a gameobject is created for the musicplayer, of course. When I try to turn it off again, the music stays on and a second musicplayer gameobject is created. I don't understand what is going on.

```
void Start () 
{
    checkWhatsOn();
}

void checkWhatsOn()
{
    bool sound = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Sound Playing", 1) == 1;
    //if (sound) soundToggle.isOn = true;  //THESE TWO STATEMENTS
    //else soundToggle.isOn = false;       //ARE CAUSING THE ISSUE!!
}

public void switchSound()
{
    print (string.Format("In switch method sound is {0}", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Sound Playing", 6)));
    bool sound = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Sound Playing", 1) == 1;
    if (sound)
    {
        if (GameObject.FindObjectOfType<MusicPlayer>() != null)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Sound Playing", 0);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
            GameObject.FindObjectOfType<MusicPlayer>().GetComponent<MusicPlayer>().Disable();
        }
        else print ("Sound wasn't changed, MusicPlayer needs to be null.");
    }
    else if (!sound)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Sound Playing", 1);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        if (GameObject.FindObjectOfType<MusicPlayer>() == null)
        {
            musicPlayer = Instantiate (Resources.Load ("MusicPlayer")) as GameObject;
            GameObject.DontDestroyOnLoad(musicPlayer);
        }
        else print ("Sound wasn't changed, MusicPlayer shouldn't be null.");
    }
    print (string.Format("After switch method sound is {0}", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Sound Playing", 7)));
}
```

In the inspector I have the "On" button call the function above while passing in a 1. When "Off" pressed, it calls the same function with a 0.

**9/2/14**

I have updated my code using only one toggle button. The toggle button calls a method which checks the PlayerPrefs to see whether the sound should be on or not. I still end up with an issue when I move from one scene into the scene that has the toggle button in it. When I do that, the music stops. It is for some reason calling the method that should only be called when the toggle button is pressed. Any ideas?

**9/4/15**

After testing what Thaina had told me (code updated above), I narrowed my issue down to the fact that if I try to set my toggle button to on, it automatically calls the function that is attached to the toggle. I only want to have the function called if it is pressed, not when setting it's saved state. Is there a way to do this?

**SOLUTION**

I ended up just letting the toggle.isOn call the function that it was trying to access and used a static bool to only let it access certain code when I wanted it to. Thaina's answer is what got me far enough to get to that point so credit goes to Thaina.

Comment: why are you using two toggle buttons for single purpose..??

Comment: @rj so the buttons could be used to call a method with two diffe re not values while both being set up in the inspector

Comment: @rj I updated my post using only one toggle button. I have gotten it to work mostly but you will see my issue in the edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you should use `GameObject.FindObjectOfType<MusicPlayer>()`. So you can be sure that it will get MusicPlayer in the scene

I suspect that your MusicPlayer object is actually named "MusicPlayer " not "MusicPlayer". Anyway get object by its name is bad idea in my opinion. It prone to error

Comment: I have no idea what you mean because you're saying it is not MusicPlayer but is MusicPlayer. Same name? And I have made sure that I am specifying the correct name. And what do you think is better than using a name? I'd prefer not to be prone to error. Lol

Comment: Not the same name. "MusicPlayer " has space character so it not equal to "MusicPlayer". Because when you instantiate "MusicPlayer" it would be named "MusicPlayer (Clone)" and your code strip "(Clone)" which left a space character there

Comment: @saboehnke And FindObjectOfType using Type not string name. It return object of the type you specified, precisely get MonoBehavior you created. Unlike Find which using string and return GameObject. Using generic properly instead of name always lessen error in C#. string is too dynamic

Comment: Also if you if(bool) then else. You don't need to else if(!bool)

Comment: Okay I will give that a shot...and yes I know I didn't need the else if (!bool) there. I was just being 100% precise when trying to figure out exactly why it was doing what it was doing.

Comment: I have narrowed it down using what you showed me. When I set soundToggle.isOn = true, it calls the method attached to the toggle button. Is there a way that I can save the state of the check box for the toggle and set it to that state when it loads without it calling the function attached to it?

Comment: No idea. Maybe you should change your attached method from onvaluechanged to onclick

Comment: I ended up getting around it just by only letting anything access that function when a static bool was set to true. I set it to false when it was not being accessed when it should. Problem solved. Thank you for your help. Your pointer helped.